# jQuery Datepicker format, from mm-dd-yy to dd-mm-yy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, datepicker

As the title says, I would like to change the datepicker format from `mm-dd-yy` to `dd-mm-yy`.

Here's my full code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $("input[name='something']").val(dateText);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form action="step2.php" method="post">
  <div type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"></div>
  <input type="text" name="something" value="Date">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `dateFormat` property to `"dd-mm-yy"` when initializing the datepicker.

By default, the value of `dateFormat` is `"mm/dd/yy"`. See [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/mnzwhjes/)

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $("input[name='something']").val(dateText);
    }
});
```